# 14.04 upgrade: sysklogd disappeared without replacement!

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, syslog

I just upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 with `do-release-upgrade` and I lost my syslog daemon in the proceedings. klogd and sysklogd were removed without any replacement functionality being installed. (I only noticed once I realized my Postfix logs hadn't updated since the upgrade!)

When I try to `apt-get install sysklogd` I see:

```
Package sysklogd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
....
E: Package 'sysklogd' has no installation candidate
```

I installed `syslog-ng` instead and I guess everything is working.

Here's `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`: https://gist.github.com/tdsmith/11132673

My questions:

1. It's a bug that my system had no syslog capability after the upgrade, right?
2. Where should I report it?

Comment: Was it replaced with rsyslog?

Comment: @ChrisR., it was not. `dpkg -l rsyslog` shows status "un" (i.e. never installed). I don't think I had any syslog capability because neither /var/log/syslog or /var/log/mail.log updated for several hours after the upgrade. Chatter resumed in both after installing syslog-ng (and apt-get didn't remove any conflicting packages when I installed it).